# Finding Nearest Points is not returning right answer

Tags: c, math

I have to find the points that are the closest to each other. I wrote my code and it should work (I did it in java, and it worked fine, and then I translated it to C).

The C program keeps printing out the wrong answer (0.0) (0.0).

The right answer is (1.0, 1.0) (2.0, 0.5)

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double nearest(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);

int main(){
    double temp1 = 0;
    double temp2 = 0;
    double temp3 = 0;
    double temp4 = 0;

    double points[8][2] = {
        {-1, 3},
        {-1, -1},
        {1, 1},
        {2, 0.5},
        {2, -1},
        {3, 3},
        {4, 2},
        {4, -0.5}
    };

    double minimum = nearest(points[0][0], points[0][1], points[1][0], points[1][1]);

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < points[i][j]; j++){
            double distance = nearest(points[i][0], points[i][1], points[j][0], points[j][1]);

            if(minimum > distance){
                minimum = nearest(points[i][0], points[i][1], points[j][0], points[j][1]);

                temp1 = points[i][0];
                temp2 = points[i][1];
                temp3 = points[j][0];
                temp4 = points[j][1];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("(%lf, %lf) (%lf, %lf)\n", temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4);
}

double nearest(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    return sqrt((pow(x2 - x1, 2)) + (pow(y2 - y1, 2)));
}
```

Comment: You initialized `mininum` to the distance between the first two points, but you didn't initialise the `temp` variables. So If nothing shorter than `minimum` appears in your loop, you output the wrong answer.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The min isn't 0 though

Comment: @r3mainer how do i fix that?

Comment: @JustTryingToCode: Sorry, I misread.

Comment: For example, initialize `minimum` to -1, and change `if(minimum > distance)` to `if(minimum == -1 || minimum > distance)`

Comment: Your inner loop test looks wrong.  `j < points[i][j]` should just be `j < 8`.

Comment: Your assignment to `minimum` inside the loop is needlessly repeating work it's already done.  Just use `minimum = distance;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major problems in for code:

1. If the two first points in the set are the closest you will never change the value for your `temp` variables. I would also suggest to not hold the xy values in temp variables but the indices of the (so far) closest points.
2. In the second for loop you check for `j < points[i][j]` which is not correct. It should be `j < 8`.

I would also suggest that the check for the first loop should be `i < 7` becauese for `i = 7` you dont have to check any distance.